# Devise Registration URL could not be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a problem with devise after customizing the signup - route.
The devise doc mentions, that routes can easily be customized, so I tried to add a token to the URL to set up a easy invitation system. Ist really straight forward and all I did was adding

```
devise_for :users, :path_names => { :sign_up => "signup/:invitation_token" }
```

to my routes. A mailer sends an email with the token and inside I pass

```
new_user_registration_path(@invitation.token)
```

rake routes says

```
 new_user_registration GET    /users/signup/:invitation_token(.:format)     devise/registrations#new
```

But I'm still getting

```
 No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations", :locale=>:de, :invitation_token=>nil}
```

I get it wether I pass the token or not...

I'm not shure what I'm missing.
Thanks in advance, hope someones sees what I'm doing wrong.

Greets, Rob

Comment: Have you looked at [devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable)?

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll try that, but I also want to understand, what I'm doin' wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Check `@invitation.token` to make sure that it's not `nil`.

The error you're witnessing will occur on any view in which you pass `nil` into your `new_user_registration_path` link tag.

Bear in mind that you'll need to override the default behavior of Devise's `users/registration` controller in order to get your invitation system working correctly. Something like this would work:

```
# routes.rb
devise_for :users, :path_names => { :sign_up => "signup/:invitation_token" }, :controllers => {:registrations => "users/registrations"}

# app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def create
        # add custom create logic here
    end
end
```